# No field extension is "degree 4 away from an algebraic closure"

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Question: Suppose $[L:K]=4$, $\operatorname{char}K \neq 2$ and $L$ is algebraically closed. Show that there is an intermediate field $M$ such that $[L:M]=2$ and $X^2 + 1$ splits over $M$. Show that this leads to a contradiction.

I have successfully found such $M$. Would somebody please give me some hints to the last part?

Comment: Can you please explain how you construct $M$ ?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg $L:K$ is Galois by the hypotheses.

Comment: @user71815: really? Where did you read that hypothesis?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Okay, my Galois theory is rusty, but let me try: $L$ is the algebraic closure of $K$, so $L:K$ is normal. $[L:K]$ and the fields' characteristic are coprime, so $L:K$ is separable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a $i\in M$ such that $i^2=(-1)$. Since
$[L:M]=2$, there is a $d\in M$ such that $L=M(\sqrt{d})$.

Since $L$ is algebraically closed, there is a $\alpha\in L$
such that $\alpha^2=\sqrt{d}$. 
You can write $\alpha=x+y\sqrt{d}$ with $x,y\in M$. Then
$\alpha^2=(x^2+dy^2)+(2xy)\sqrt{d}$, and
$x^2+dy^2=0, 2xy=1$ (why?).
Now, $y\neq 0$ (why?), so $(\frac{x}{y})^2=-d$, $(i\frac{x}{y})^2=d$.
Notice that $i\frac{x}{y} \in M$, and deduce a contradiction from this.

Comment: Dear Ewan, you implicitly suppose that $i\notin K$. Why is that?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Dear Georges, my original presentation indeed gave that mistaken impression. I just corrected that, thanks. In fact, once $M$ has been found (and the OP claims to have already dealt with that so I leave that part aside) $K$ leaves the scene and does not play any role in the rest of the proof.

Comment: Ah, thanks Ewan. Now I'll ask the OP how he justifies his claim !