# No field extension is “degree 4 away from an algebraic closure”

Tags: galois-theory

I have seen this problem asked by another user but it isn't completely solved in the answers. I'm trying to do it, but I can't.

Question: Suppose $[L:K]=4$ and $charK≠2$ and $L$ is algebraically closed. Show that there is an intermediate field M such that $[L:M]=2$ and that $X^2+1$ splits over $M$. Show that this leads to a contradiction.

I can't show that this M exists, and for this reason, I can't follow with the other parts.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Can you give the link to the other Question?  It might help us to isolate a more specific question that you need help answering.

Comment: What does it mean to say that $[L:K]=4$?

Comment: @JohnHabert : I am not able to write properly.. I know that by $[L:K]=4$ $L$ is a $4$ dimensional vector space when viewed with base field $K$ but then i am not able to write precisely in terms of minimal polynomials or galois theory terms...

Comment: This is the link.
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/615604/homework-no-field-extension-is-degree-4-away-from-an-algebraic-closure/665987#665987

I don't know if the question is correct. Maybe not. I'm with you John. I don't have enought hipotesis... you can't use normality, separability, finite field... nothing.

Comment: And there are other problem. It's impossible to give a counterexample because the last question is "show that hypothesis are impossible"...

Comment: I was asking my question to try and elicit some work. It is fairly easy to show there is an $M$ as described above.

Answer (score 0):

Case 1: $x^2+1$ does not split over $K$. Simply take $M$ as the splitting field of $x^2+1$.

Case 2: $x^2+1$ splits over $K$, so I only need to find some extension $M/K$ of degree $2$. $L/K$ is a finite Galois extension because $L$ is algebraically closed. $\operatorname{Gal}(L/K)$ has order $4$, hence it has an element $\sigma$ of order two. You can take $M$ as the field fixed by $\sigma$.